# UITextInput: How Do I Show the Caret for a Custom UIView That Implements the UITextInput Protocol?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, caret, uitextinput

I notice in Apple's `UITextInput` protocol there is a required method called `(CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position` that, as you can see, returns a `CGRect`. When I put a breakpoint inside of the method, it appears the method is never called even when I call the `setSelectedTextRange:` method. Do I have to implement my own caret object inside the text view? I thought the protocol automatically handled this and just added the caret into the text view with the frame specified by the `CGRect` returned by `caretRectForTextPosition:`. How would I go about showing/adding a caret to my `UIView` class that implements the `UITextInput` protocol?

**EDIT**

I have read the documentation all up and down with no results and even searched for example implementations by other people. I eventually just implemented the caret myself. Is that the right/suggested way to even do this?

Comment: What do the official docs say?

Comment: That's my issue. I have read the documentation all up and down with no results and even searched for example implementations by other people. I eventually just implemented the caret myself.

Comment: These details should be included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have to implement the caret yourself. See Apple's [SimpleTextInput](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread looking for an answer to this question 9 years later.  Modern answer: if you've implemented the UITextInput protocol properly (including caretRectForPosition) and attach a UITextInteraction, e.g. from the containing view:

```swift
let textInteraction = UITextInteraction(for: .editable)
textInteraction.textInput = self
addInteraction(textInteraction)
```

then UITextInteraction will handle the cursor display.

Comment: Oh wow! Nice, I'll have to give this a shot. Can you update your answer with references to documentation?